# Showing B is not derivable from A

Tags: logic

Let's take it that under the assumption of A, ~C is true. And let's also take it that if ~C is true and if B is derivable from A, then C is true.

I want to show that B is not derivable from A. Is this possible under these assumptions? It seems like we can assume that B is derivable from A for the sake of obtaining a contradiction. So there is some proof that begins by assuming A and obtains B in a finite amount of steps. We take that derivation under which we already have A as an assumption and within it, since we know that A gives ~C, we conclude that ~C is true. Now since we also know that if ~C and if B is derivable from A, then C is true. So we get to a contradiction, and so B is not provable from A. Is this valid? Or does this only show that under the assumption that B is derivable from A, then ~A is derivable by the empty set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the argument you're trying to construct is valid.

As you can see below, a truth table in which $A$ is false, $B$ is true, and $C$ is true will show it is possible for your premises $A \to \neg C$ and $[\neg C \wedge (A \to B) ] \to C$ to be true and the conclusion $\neg (A \to B)$ to be false. Hence, the argument is invalid.

$
\begin{array}{llllllllllllllll}
A & \to & \neg & C & \Big| & [\neg & C & \wedge & (A & \to & B) ] & \to & C & \Big|\Big| & \neg & (A & \to & B) \\
0 & \:\color{red}{1} & 0 & 1 && \:\:0 & 1 & 0 & \:\:0 & \:1 & 1 & \:\color{red}{1} & 1 && \:\color{red}{0} & \:\:0 & \:1 & 1
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

Assume A $\supset$ B.  (for contradiction)

Assume ($\lnot$ C $\land$ (A $\supset$ B)) $\supset$ C. (gathered from your question)

($\lnot$ C $\land$ True) $\supset$ C.  (replacing A implies B with its truth value)

$\lnot$ C $\supset$ C.  (reducing "and True")

$\lnot$ C only implies C if $\lnot$ C is false.

We can conclude that C is true under the assumptions.  But this isn't a contradiction.  Instead, using Implication, $\lnot$ C $\supset$ C is equivalent to C $\lor$ C.  Maybe another answerer can find a contradiction but I don't.

Quoting your first paragraph, "let's also take it that if $\lnot$ C is true and if B is derivable from A, then C is true."  Let's say instead, "if $\lnot$ C is true and *anything*, then C is true."  It seems like you are trying to conjure up a contradiction with these C terms, then stick it onto the A and B term.  I couldn't make it work.

Is there a particular problem that inspires the question?  We should be able to work with the symbols but I am just curious.

Comment: You have that given A, ~C follows. Does this also imply that A is false, then?

Comment: I think you're right.  Sorry I missed that.  But with A false, A $\supset$ B is true (a falsehood implies anything) does that help?